# Do we need to disambiguate the "gaming" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Gaming in the computational sense really refers to video games which are distinct from combinatorial games (board games, card games, etc.)

My feeling is that the approach to these general categories has been distinct, and only recently have algorithms proven on combinatorial games been extended to video games (AlphaGo).

- Should we add a "combinatorial-games" tag and replace the gaming tag on questions relating to Chess or Go, for example?

Comment: I don't know how games are made but as far as I heard shouldn't combinatorial games be those games in which all future outcomes are known? In chess the outcomes are very large to be computed and rest of most games (survival, strategy) follow the rule of different result for different decisions...so the remaining games like (fps, arcade shooting games) should really have no aspect of AI and so its unlikely people will ask questions about those under the gaming tag...

Comment: By rpg i meant fps games

Comment: @DuttaA Combinatorial Game Theory seems to be a fairly esoteric field, and the scope is always expanding based on what games can be fruitfully mathematically analyzed.  (I researched the field for a couple of years and was finally forced to reach out to some luminaries to get a handle on it.)  Intractability is not a requirement, but the focus in CGT is definitely solving games mathematically.  Tic-tac-toe is trivially solved and useful for that reason.

Comment: @DuttaA General game AI is a huge field (most AI for complex games suck today, but that is surely a temporary condition based on how NNs are performing against humans in games with significantly fewer parameters.  Of course, there's a greater "combinatorial explosion" to contend with in the high-level games...)  But, for instance, there is a current drive to develop a machine learning algorithm that can beat the top humans at Starcraft.  When they achieve it, it will be a very big deal: https://www.technologyreview.com/s/609242/humans-are-still-better-than-ai-at-starcraftfor-now/

Comment: Side note: In my experience, even the most complex 4x games out today pale in comparison to Chess and Go in terms of strategic depth and nuance.  In other words, high-level games with hundreds of rules are not as deep as the most durable intractable abstract games b/c it's about compactness-to-complexity ratio, not sheer complexity.  Compact combinatorial games are the most efficient chaotic systems I am aware of.